# RSHINY - How to write rhandsontable to csv file?

Tags: function, save, export-to-csv, rhandsontable, rshiny

I have a problem in RShiny. Below I show code from 2 files:

```
# File app.R
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
source("myscript.R")
library(rhandsontable)
shinyUI<-fluidPage(
fluidRow(
    titlePanel(title = "Application in RSHINY"),
    textInput("text1", "Give numbers with commas","1,3,12,18"),
    submitButton("Update!"),
    column(8,actionButton("saveBtn","Save"),rHandsontableOutput("table"))))

shinyServer<-function(input,output,session){  
    output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
    arg=(strsplit(input$text1,",") %>% unlist() %>% as.numeric())
    tabelaa=dataframe_FUNCTION(arg)
    rownames(tabelaa)=paste("Row",1:4,sep="")
    rhandsontable(format(tabelaa, digits=0),width=400,rowHeaderWidth=300)
})
}
shinyApp(ui=shinyUI, server=shinyServer)
```

Problem 1) When I change value in rhandsontable and click on button Update,
I want to change rhandsontable values automatically.
Problem 2) How to write current rhandsonetable to csv file

```
## myscript.R
dataframe_FUNCTION<-function(...){
aa=list(...)
my_df=data.frame(aa)
colnames(my_df)="COL"
return(my_df^2)
}
```

Comment: Updating the table when changing an input value works fine when running your code, so there is no problem 1. 

For your problem 2, use a `downloadButton` instead of the `actionButton`, make your tabelaa as a [reactive expression](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson6/) outside of the `renderRHandsontable()` function and use a `downloadHandler()` function ([see the tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/download.html)) linked to the `downloadButton` to export the `tabelaa()` expression as .csv.